# How do I find the normalize value from a given set of data?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of data like `{{x1, y1},{x2, y2}, ...,{xn, yn}}`.

Using this - `Sort[data, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &][[1]]` I could find the value of x at which value of y is max.

My target is to normalize the data set prior to performing integration.

Please help me to solve it as I am a beginner in Mathematica. I am using Mathematica 11.3.

Comment: What is expected for data like `{{0, 0}, {1, -10}, {2, 3}}`?

Answer (score 2):

[`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html) is almost certainly the function you're looking for. First just set everything up.

```
SeedRandom[1337];
data = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10, 2}]
(*
{{-7.82821, 89.1084}, {99.7236, -96.2896}, {38.0613, -50.3881}, {11.2803, -9.44228}, 
 {-10.5295, -55.573}, {-53.8737, 61.9644}, {75.3992, -6.71107}, {-22.884, -40.2397},
 {-59.4771, 77.2297}, {-79.1672, 48.3519}}
*)
sorted = Reverse@SortBy[data, Last]
(*
{{-7.82821, 89.1084}, {-59.4771, 77.2297}, {-53.8737, 61.9644}, 
 {-79.1672, 48.3519}, {75.3992, -6.71107}, {11.2803, -9.44228}, 
 {-22.884, -40.2397}, {38.0613, -50.3881}, {-10.5295, -55.573}, 
 {99.7236, -96.2896}}
*)
```

If you want all the values ($x$ and $y$) normalized together, you can just use `Rescale` directly:

```
together = Rescale[sorted]
(* 
{{0.451303, 0.945844}, {0.187806, 0.885243}, {0.216393, 0.807364}, {0.0873531, 0.737917},
 {0.875904, 0.457002}, {0.548789, 0.443069}, {0.374493, 0.285949}, {0.685417, 0.234175},
 {0.437522, 0.207723}, {1., 0.}}
*)
```

Two uses of `Transpose` and a `Map` will normalize the $x$s and $y$s independently:

```
separate = Transpose /* Map[Rescale] /* Transpose@sorted
{{0.398785, 1.}, {0.110068, 0.935929}, {0.141391, 0.853591}, {0., 
  0.780168}, {0.864026, 0.483169}, {0.505602, 0.468437}, {0.314623, 
  0.302322}, {0.655307, 0.247583}, {0.383685, 0.219617}, {1., 0.}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234]

data = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10, 2}]

(* {{75.3217, 4.39285}, {-82.7553, -24.4174}, {-97.6711, 
  85.4532}, {8.75135, -4.13367}, {-50.9302, 
  51.9792}, {96.9986, -56.591}, {-8.19656, 
  76.9458}, {16.7709, -47.2054}, {83.912, -15.233}, {97.4581, 17.5885}} *)

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]

(* {-97.6711, 97.4581} *)

{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]]

(* {-56.591, 85.4532} *)

normData = {(#[[1]] - xmin)/(xmax - xmin),
     (#[[2]] - ymin)/(ymax - ymin)} & /@ data;

MinMax[normData[[All, 1]]]

(* {0., 1.} *)

MinMax[normData[[All, 2]]]

(* {0., 1.} *)
```

**EDIT:** Or perhaps

```
normData2 = #/(Norm[#, Infinity] & /@ Transpose[data]) & /@ data;

MinMax[normData2[[All, 1]]]

(* {-1., 0.997819} *)

MinMax[normData2[[All, 2]]]

(* {-0.662245, 1.} *)
```

**EDIT2:** For the result given in your comment, you presumably want

```
Clear["Global`*"]

x = {8, 8.35714, 8.74766, 9.17647, 9.64948, 10.1739, 10.7586, 11.4146, 
   12.1558, 13};
y = {0.69374, 0.695, 0.63036, 0.64356, 0.82135, 0.97686, 0.93261, 0.90566, 
   0.91163, 0.95223};

xmax = Max@x;

ymax = Max@y;

xNorm = x/xmax;

yNorm = y/ymax;

f = Interpolation[Transpose[{xNorm, yNorm}],
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Integrate[f[t], {t, Min@xNorm, 1}]

(* 0.332249 *)
```

Comment: x=[8 ,8.35714, 8.74766, 9.17647, 9.64948, 10.1739, 10.7586, 11.4146, 12.1558, 13]
y=[0.69374, 0.695, 0.63036, 0.64356, 0.82135, 0.97686, 0.93261, 0.90566, 0.91163, 0.95223]I need to normalize x and y of the above data set and then want to integrate the normalized data set. My target integral result is 0.3322. Thank you very much for the aforesaid suggestions but I am unable to get my desired result. So if you can kindly let me know how it could be solved.

Comment: The "data" in your comment are not lists.

Comment: I separated x and its corresponding y data points.

Comment: Which has nothing to do with the data given not being lists. See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)